# ActiveRecord: Reassign children by looping a collection fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I was working on a homework assignment (the SaaS part 2 course on edx.org). 
Essentially, we have two blog articles, and each article has associated comments. So the goal is to combine two articles into one by creating a third article. That also means, carrying over comments from the first two articles into the third article.

In my code, my first approach is..
assuming the method signature is `def merge_with(other_article_id)`, and `self` refers to first article, `other_article` refers to second article, and `new_article` refers to the newly created third article (note that the `new_article` is already saved with a primary key assigned)

```
self.comments do |comment|
  new_article.comments << comment
end
other_article.comments do |comment|
  new_article.comments << comment
end     
new_article.save
debugger
```

Under debugger, if I do `e new_article.comments`, it returns empty `[]` but **I am very puzzled as to why that's the case**.

The current work around is

`new_article.comments = self.comments + other_article.comments`

, and that allows me to finish my homework, but still, its bugs me to no end as to why collection looping approach does not work.

One last question would be.. **are there any recommended approach when it comes to reassign child to another parent** (in this example reassign comment from one article to another)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I would be tempted to debug inside the loop to see what the value of comment is and to ensure it is actually being called.  Shouldn't ot be: self.comments.each do |comment| ...?  Perhaps you are missing a call to "each"

Comment: Oh boy.. I can't believe I missed such a tiny detail. Yes, `.each` is the missing key. It is a little weird because, when I was debugging, I felt like I was iterating through the loop.